# Accessing another object from logged in User

Tags: grails, spring-security, gsp

I am using Spring security with Grails.  My User has username and it also has a reference to another Domain object called Seller.

```
// Every user will usually be associated with a Seller
static belongsTo = [seller: Seller];
```

In GSPs, I can display the username of logged in User by doing:

```
<sec:ifLoggedIn>Hello <sec:username/> </sec:ifLoggedIn>
```

But I'd like to also display a property from the user's seller object.   I try:

```
<sec:ifLoggedIn>Hello <sec:username/> <sec:seller.name/> </sec:ifLoggedIn>
```

But that gives:

```
Tag [seller.name] does not exist. No tag library found for namespace: sec
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own taglib to render the name of the current user, like

```
class TestTagLib {
    static final namespace = 'myTag'

    def name = { attrs ->
        User user = springSecurityService.currentUser as User
        out << user.name
    }
}
```

and use it where you want to show name

```
<sec:ifLoggedIn>Hello <sec:username/> <myTag:name/> </sec:ifLoggedIn>
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the previous answer is more flexible,if you just want to show the logged in username you can try either of these tags:

```
<sec:ifLoggedIn>Hello ${sec.username} </sec:ifLoggedIn>
```

or

```
<sec:ifLoggedIn>Hello ${sec.loggedInUserInfo(field:'username')} </sec:ifLoggedIn>
```